# Swift, moving content behind keyboard doesn't reset after dismiss

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, swift, keyboard

I have a uiscrollview in one of my VC's. Inside the scrollView,i have multiple TF's, Buttons, etc. Im using the code below, per Apple documentation, to move the scrollView up when a keyboard notification is called, to push up the hidden text fields. However, when I close the keyboard, the scrollView doesn't reset or move back down, it simply stays at the "moved up" location.

Am I missing something here? I have a member variable of the class called:

```
var activeTextField: UITextField!
```

Am i using this correctly with the delegate methods?

```
(func registerForKeyboardNotifications() {
    let notificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self,
        selector: "keyboardWillBeShown:",
        name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification,
        object: nil)
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self,
        selector: "keyboardWillBeHidden:",
        name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification,
        object: nil)
}

func keyboardWillBeShown(sender: NSNotification) {
    let info: NSDictionary = sender.userInfo!
    let value: NSValue = info.valueForKey(UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey) as NSValue
    let keyboardSize: CGSize = value.CGRectValue().size
    let contentInsets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize.height, 0.0)
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

    // If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
    // Your app might not need or want this behavior.
    var aRect: CGRect = self.view.frame
    aRect.size.height -= keyboardSize.height
    let activeTextFieldRect: CGRect? = activeTextField?.frame
    let activeTextFieldOrigin: CGPoint? = activeTextFieldRect?.origin
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeTextFieldOrigin!)) {
        scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(activeTextFieldRect!, animated:true)
    }
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
func keyboardWillBeHidden(sender: NSNotification) {
    let contentInsets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField!) {
    activeTextField = textField
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = true
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField!) {
    activeTextField = nil
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = false
}


override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.registerForKeyboardNotifications()
}

override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! Your code came in handy!

Comment: Nice code! I was trying it out, but on mine the view doesn't even go up, do you know why?

Answer (score 2):

You have to **change** the first line of `keyboardWillBeHidden`

instead of:

```
let contentInsets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
```

write:

```
let insets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.scrollView.contentInset.top, 0, 0, 0)
```

I hope help you

Answer (score 2):

I did this and it worked for me. Seems a lot easier then your way. I used a UITextView for my project. But it should work the same with a UITextField. The -/+ 25 was just to allow the title to be shown.

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    myScrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, textView.frame.origin.y-25), animated: true)
}

func textViewDidEndEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    myScrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, -textView.frame.origin.y+25), animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Anna's answer, you should also use
`let contentInsets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.scrollView.contentInset.top, 0.0, keyboardSize.height, 0.0)` in `keyboardWillBeShown` to avoid that a text view disappears underneath the navigation bar.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that

```
var activeTextField: UITextField!
```

You should replace activeTextField with the other UITextField (e.g. a textfield that exists in the storyboard), and you can find that the scrollview can scroll when the keyboard appears.